# Populate multiple textboxes from dropdown - CodeIgniter/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dropdown

I have CodeIgniter project I'd like to "upgrade" :)
In one part of it I'm selecting a value (primary key) from table and displaying all the data from that record. Currently I'm using dropdown menu for selection and a button to start a query which then shows the data on the same page.
Table has following fields:

```
claim_id - primary key
repair_type
type
block
condition
defect
symptom
repair
addition
```

My Model:

```
class Claim_m extends MY_Model
{
   protected $_table_name = 'claim';            
   protected $_order_by = 'repair_type';            
   protected $_primary_key = 'claim_id';

   public function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
   }

   public $rules_claim = array(
    'repair_type'=>array(
        'field'=>'claim_id', 
        'label'=>'ID Claima', 
        'rules'=>'required'
        )
    );

    public function daj_dropdown()   //creates dropdown
    {
       $rezultat = $this->db->select('claim_id,repair_type')->get('claim')->result_array();
       $dropdown = array();
       foreach($rezultat as $r)
       {
           $dropdown[$r['claim_id']] = $r['repair_type'];
       }
       return $dropdown;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
   class Claims extends Frontend_Controller
   {
       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->model('claim_m');
       }


       public function choice()
       {
           //validation 
           $rules = $this->claim_m->rules_claim;
           $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

           if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
           {
               $claim_id = $this->input->post('claim_id');
               $this->data['zapisi'] = $this->claim_m->daj($claim_id,TRUE);
           }

           //dropdown
           $this->data['dropdown'] = $this->claim_m->daj_dropdown();

           //set subview
           $this->data['subview'] = 'claim/zapis';


          $this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->data);
       }
   }
```

My View (zapis.php):

```
<?php echo form_open();?>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Type of repair:</td>
            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('claim_id',$dropdown);  ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Izaberi', 'class="btn btn-primary"');  ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<?php
    if(!isset($zapisi))
    {
        echo 'no records';
    }
    else
    { ?>
        <section>
            <h2>Claim pattern - <u> <?php echo($zapisi->repair_type); ?> </u></h2>


            <i>Defect type: </i><font color="red"><?php echo($zapisi->type); ?></font></br>
            <i>Defect block: </i><font color="red"><?php echo($zapisi->block); ?></font></br>
            <i>Condition code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo($zapisi->condition);  ?></font></br>
            <i>Defect code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo($zapisi->defect); ?></font></br>
            <i>Symptom code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo($zapisi->symptom); ?></font></br>
            <i>Repair code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo($zapisi->repair); ?></font></br>
            <i>Other: </i></br><font color="red"><?php echo($zapisi->addition); ?></font></br>
        </section>
    <?php } ?>
```

**All of this works fine** but I need to make it without button on the view. Basically I need to write down all the other fields whenever selection is changed in dropdown menu without need to press button. I've found out about tutorial when one filed is needed but I need to present (after change in dropdown menu) 7 fields from MySQL database table (type, block, condition, defect, symptom, repair, addition).

I don't know much about jQuery or Ajax but I presume its needed for something like this. If somebody can help me with this or point me to the right tutorial I would be grateful.
Thank you in advance!

Edit: function daj() from MY_Model

```
public function daj($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
        {
            if ($id != NULL)
            {
                $filter = $this->_primary_filter; 
                $id = $filter($id); 
                $this->db->where($this->_primary_key,$id); 
                $method = 'row';
            }
            elseif($single == TRUE)
            {
                $method = 'row';
            }
            else
            {
                $method = 'result';
            }

            $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
            return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
        }
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and including `claim_m->daj()` in the model code?

Comment: Hi DFriend I've added it.

Comment: What you do know is submit the form on button click and then show the data on refresh? Do you want to do it without overloading the page, or the reload is fine, you just want to trigger it on the dropdown change?

Comment: Just on a trigger on the dropdown change. Reload would be basicaly same as using the button :)

Comment: Just posted an answer. I tried to cover the basics, but I'd advise you to spend some time to understand asynchronous calls better before starting the implementation. It's definitely not something that you can go on without :)

Comment: Thank you trajcevska, this is far beyond my knowledge :) when you mentioned reload, did you mean manual reload or automatic on change? I'll surely take a look at link you provided :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data on a dropdown change, without having to reload the page, you have to go with asynchronous call. 
I'd suggest using jQuery AJAX, you can check the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Check the example below. The details for the request are set in the object sent to the ajax, it should be pretty straightforward. The data is sent as an object, but you can also send an entire form by passing `$('#form_id').serialize()` as the data.

Then in the done method, you can catch any data sent as a response (msg in the example) and use it as you need.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST"
  url: "test.html",
  data: {field1:'Field1', field2:'Field2'}
}).done(function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

Back to your problem. You need to setup this kind of snippet where the URL should be set to your controller's function. The data you should send to the ajax is the value of the dropdown box. Let's say the id of the field is 'dropdownId'. Then the data will be `data: {selection: $('#dropdownId').val() }`.

Now you just need to adjust the response of the controller - echo it to be able to read it from the javascript.

A good practice is to return a JSON and then parse it on the front end. You can create an array with all fields you want to return, then encode it in JSON in your controller and echo it.

```
$arr = ['field1' => 'Val1', 'field2' => 'Val2'];
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Then in the done function of your ajax call, you'll have:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
```

And you can access the fields like:

```
obj.field1, obj.field2...
```

Then you'll just need to set the values of the fields (ids are field1, field2 etc.):

```
$('#field1').val(obj.field1);
$('#field2').val(obj.field2);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to use JQuery to request new html when the dropdown changes.

Add this function to the controller `Claims.php`

```
public function new_select() {
  $claim_id = $this->input->post('claim_id');
  $data['zapisi'] = $this->claim_m->daj($claim_id, TRUE);
  //output the sub-subview it will be recieved by the ajax success function
  $this->load->view('claim_detail', $data);
}
```

`new_select()` will be used by a JQuery ajax call shown later.

Change the view file `zapis.php` to this

```
<div>Type of repair:</div>
<div>
  <?php echo form_dropdown('claim_id', $dropdown, NULL, array('id' => 'repair_select')); ?>
</div>
<section id="repair-detail">
  <?php
  $this->load->view('claim_detail');
  ?>
</section>
```

Note that an `id` attribute was added to the dropdown. Also note the above loads a sub-sub-view which is a new view file - `claim_detail.php` - as follows.

```
<h2>
  Claim pattern - <u><?php echo isset($zapisi) ? $zapisi->repair_type : "No Repair type selected"; ?></u>
</h2>
<div><?php
  if(isset($zapisi))
  {
    ?>
    <i>Defect type: </i><font color="red"><?php echo $zapisi->type; ?></font><br>
    <i>Defect block: </i><font color="red"><?php echo $zapisi->block; ?></font><br>
    <i>Condition code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo $zapisi->condition; ?></font><br>
    <i>Defect code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo $zapisi->defect; ?></font><br>
    <i>Symptom code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo $zapisi->symptom; ?></font><br>
    <i>Repair code: </i><font color="red"><?php echo $zapisi->repair; ?></font><br>
    <i>Other: </i><br><font color="red"><?php echo $zapisi->addition; ?></font><br>
    <?php
  }
  ?></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //handle changes to the dropdown
    $("#repair_select").on('change', function (event) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "claims/new_select",
        data: {claim_id: $(this).val()}, //send new select id to server
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (returned) {
          //replace the html inside <section id="repair-detail"> with the returned html
          $("#repair-detail").html(returned);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

The new view has javascript to handle the dropdown change event. Basically it notices a change in the dropdown and sends the newly selected `claim_id` to the controller function `new_select` which replies by sending back html populated by the database values. The ajax function `success:` replaces the html inside `<section id="repair-detail">` with the `returned` html. The page is dynamically updated with new content!

I didn't test this so please forgive any syntax errors. But the concept is sound and is a very common solution to this type of situation.

Comment: What I didn't cover what how to load JQuery. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Works fine (one small correction only in url  claims/ is not needed). Thank you very very very much!